# Redis peer-to-peer like cluster(K8s)

Tags: redis, kubernetes

I want a redis cluster that every redis instance can access other instance's data i.e data should be replicated among themselves.(With out master-slave concept)

I'm trying to setup redis `RepilcaSet` in K8s. I tried to setup `slave-read-only no` in config which pods are restating continuously.

### Update1

I used https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/storage/redis example to setup cluster which is master-salve+Redis Sentinel. But my application can't access sentinel to know who is the redis master. That's why I don's want to use sentinel.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on your setup, configuration, and deployments? What images do you use exactly?

Comment: @jbndlr Can you please check my update1

Comment: I would suggest expanding the question some (detail what you're trying to do) and ask this on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com), where they're much more likely to have the knowledge you seek

Answer (score 0):

You can have master and slave in same node if you are short of nodes.

Replication in Redis uses the master - slave concept. you can't replicate by switching off slave. https://redis.io/topics/replication

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do mutual replication, you need to have a way to resolve 'both updated' situations and it is not that easy. You need either [CRDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type) model or a good resolver algorithm. If you just cycle the dependency (idk if it is possible), simultaneous updates on multiple nodes will propagate unpredictably.

Take a look at [SoundCloud's roshi](https://github.com/soundcloud/roshi). Maybe it will be enough for your case?